# Using sets in lean

Tags: dependent-type, formal-verification, lean

I'd like to do some work in topology using lean.

As a good start, I wanted to prove a couple of simple lemmas about [sets in lean](https://github.com/leanprover/lean/blob/master/library/init/data/set.lean).

For example

```
def inter_to_union (H : a ∈ set.inter A B) : a ∈ set.union A B :=
    sorry
```

or

```
def set_deMorgan : a ∈ set.inter A B → a ∈ set.compl (set.union (set.compl A) (set.compl B)) :=
sorry
```

or, perhaps more interestingly

```
def set_deMorgan2 : set.inter A B = set.compl (set.union (set.compl A) (set.compl B)) :=
sorry
```

But I can't find anywhere elimination rules for `set.union` or `set.inter`, so I just don't know how to work with them.

1. How do I prove the lemmas?

Also, looking at the [definition of sets in lean](https://github.com/leanprover/lean/blob/master/library/init/data/set.lean), I can see bits of syntax, which look very much like paper maths, but I don't understand at the level of dependent type theory, for example:

```
protected def sep (p : α → Prop) (s : set α) : set α :=
{a | a ∈ s ∧ p a}
```

2. How can one break down the above example into simpler notions of dependent/inductive types?

Comment: I've asked [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658919/from-set-inclusion-to-set-equality-in-lean) about the last lemma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That module identifies sets with predicates on some type `α` (`α` is usually called 'the universe'):

```
def set (α : Type u) := α → Prop
```

If you have a set `s : set α` and for some `x : α` you can prove `s a`, this is interpreted as 'x belongs to s'.

In this case, `x ∈ A` is a notation (let us not mind about typeclasses for now) for `set.mem x A` which is defined as follows:

```
protected def mem (a : α) (s : set α) :=
s a
```

The above explains why the empty set is represented as the predicate always returning `false`:

```
instance : has_emptyc (set α) :=
⟨λ a, false⟩
```

And also, the universe is unsurprisingly represented like so:

```
def univ : set α :=
λ a, true
```

I'll show how prove the first lemma:

```
def inter_to_union {α : Type} {A B : set α} {a : α} : A ∩ B ⊆ A ∪ B :=
  assume (x : α) (xinAB : x ∈ A ∩ B),        -- unfold the definition of `subset`
  have xinA : x ∈ A, from and.left xinAB,
  @or.inl _ (x ∈ B) xinA
```

This is all like the usual "pointful" proofs for these properties in basic set theory.

Regarding your question about `sep` -- you can see through notations like so:

```
set_option pp.notation false
#print set.sep
```

Here is the output:

> ```
> protected def set.sep : Π {α : Type u}, (α → Prop) → set α → set α :=
> λ {α : Type u} (p : α → Prop) (s : set α),
>   set_of (λ (a : α), and (has_mem.mem a s) (p a))
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this has been very helpful so far. How did you know that x ∈ A was a notation for `mem x A`? Did you find a file, where this notation is introduced?

Comment: The last line of your `inter_to_union` proof can be simplified to: `or.intro_left (x ∈ B) xinA`

Comment: Oh, I can see the answer to the ` x ∈ A` question: one just has to type `set_option pp.notation false
#print ∈`

Comment: Thanks again, I understand everything I wanted to understand except how to prove the last lemma, which involves equality. I'm not sure it's even provable, probably equality needs to be redefined to work with sets (set equality is not the same as `=`).

Comment: Sets are usually compared extensionally, i.e. two sets are equal iff they consist of the same elements, or equivalently they are both subsets of each other

Comment: Thanks, I've asked a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658919/from-set-inclusion-to-set-equality-in-lean)