# From set inclusion to set equality in lean

Tags: dependent-type, theorem-proving, formal-verification, lean

Given a proof of set inclusion and its converse I'd like to be able to show that two sets are equal.

For example, I know how to prove the [following statement](https://github.com/picrin/lean/blob/447f8aca14ab8fde4040a196e56b6b6f7d322d36/topology.lean#L32), and [its converse](https://github.com/picrin/lean/blob/447f8aca14ab8fde4040a196e56b6b6f7d322d36/topology.lean#L46):

```
open set

universe u
variable elem_type : Type u
variable A : set elem_type
variable B : set elem_type

def set_deMorgan_incl : A ∩ B ⊆ set.compl ((set.compl A) ∪ (set.compl B)) :=
    sorry
```

Given these two inclusion proofs, how do I prove set equality, i.e.

```
def set_deMorgan_eq : A ∩ B = set.compl ((set.compl A) ∪ (set.compl B)) :=
    sorry
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use anti-symmetry of the subset relation, as proved [in the `stdlib` package](https://github.com/leanprover/stdlib/blob/6d9072821b60d6a4a7293c943c07fba65041f25e/data/set/basic.lean#L44):

```
def set_deMorgan_eq : A ∩ B = set.compl ((set.compl A) ∪ (set.compl B)) :=
subset.antisymm (set_deMorgan_incl _ _ _) (set_deMorgan_incl_conv _ _ _)
```

As you can see in the proof of `subset.antisymm`, it combines both functional and propositional extensionality.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise one needed stdlib for this! It's somewhat a much broader question, but what are the philosophical implications of functional/ propositional extensionality?